# Printing tensor value output of model.output in keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

So I'm trying to print the value of the model.output (which is a tensor) of pretrained VGG16 model, but unfortunately all the below listed methods didn't work in my case, which I found from the previously answered similar questions.

1) Firstly on the basis of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54882511/actually-printing-values-from-tensor-object) post I tried using

> print(K.eval(model.output()))

but it threw an error as

> TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable

2) Then upon going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43448029/debugging-keras-tensor-values) post I tried using

> K.print_tensor(model.output, message='model.output = ')

approach but this time there was no output printed.

Here is my code:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import Model
import keras.backend as K
from matplotlib import pyplot
from numpy import expand_dims
import numpy as np


# load the model
model = VGG16()

img = load_img('../input/treebird/bird.jpg', target_size=(224, 224))
img = img_to_array(img)           
img = expand_dims(img, axis=0)      
img = preprocess_input(img)       

prediction = model.predict(img)

print(model.output)                                 #Tensor("predictions_19/Softmax:0",       shape=(?, 1000), dtype=float32)
print(K.eval(model.output()))                          # throws TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
K.print_tensor(model.output, message='model.output = ')
```

Am I lacking somewhere in the implementation of the above methods or are there other methods that I am supposed to use to print the tensor in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting only the relevant parts of the code.

First you will have to clear the session so that your input node in model will have same name everytime. Use `model.summary()` to know what is the input node name.

Then, you will have to make use of `feed_dict` to pass the tensor as shown in the code.

```
K.clear_session()

# load the model
model = VGG16()
model.summary()

print(model.output.eval(session=K.get_session(), feed_dict={'input_1:0': img}))
```